# вопросы по containsValue в SortedMap

Tags: java, map, сравнение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему метод `containsValue` не работает?  Нужно вручную метод проверки писать?

Если сравнивать другой массив, то они не равны, хотя в описании `Objects.equals`, который должен правильно работать...

```java
public class SUBDNOOB {
    public static class Table {
        private final SortedMap<Integer, String[]> table;
        private final String[] argNames;
        public Table(String[] argNames) {
            this.table = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o));
            this.argNames = argNames;
        }

        void add(int id, String[] args) {
            if (args.length != this.argNames.length - 1) System.out.println("wrong format");
            else {
                if (!(this.table.containsKey(id) || this.table.containsValue(args)))
                    this.table.put(id, args);
            }
        }

        String[] getArgNames() {
            return argNames;
        }

        SortedMap<Integer, String[]> getTable() {
            return table;
        }
    }

    private static Table createTable(String[] args) {
        return new Table(args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Table students = createTable(new String[] {"id", "name", "surname", "patronymic"});
        students.add(101, new String[] {"Иван", "Иванов", "Иванович"});
        System.out.println(students.getTable().containsValue(new String[] {"Иван", "Иванов", "Иванович"}));
        System.out.println(students.getTable().containsValue(students.getTable().get(101)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте больше подробностей "Оно не работает" - не информативно. Что ожидаемо должно выводится как минимум

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `Objects.equals` / `Object::equals` НЕ переопределены для массивов, чтобы сравнивать их *содержимое*, и работают так же, как для простых объектов, то есть сравнивается равенство ссылок на объект.

Для сравнения массивов по их содержимому следует использовать метод [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-).

Для решения данной проблемы есть такие способы:

- Переопределить сам метод `containsValue` при создании мапы (*писать вручную метод проверки*), чтобы для значений-массивов вызывался `Arrays.equals` и они сравнивались по содержимому:

```java
this.table = new TreeMap<>() {
    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object v) {
        if (v instanceof String[]) {
            String[] a = (String[]) v;
            for (var arr : this.values()) {
                if (Arrays.equals(arr, a)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

- Использовать список строк вместо массивов в качестве значения
  Это разумнее, так как для списков / коллекций метод `equals` переопределён, чтобы они сравнивались по содержимому:

```java
private final SortedMap<Integer, List<String>> table;
private final List<String> argNames;
public Table(String ... argNames) {
    this.table = new TreeMap<>();
    this.argNames = Arrays.asList(argNames);
}
// ...
```

*Замечание:* при создании сортированной мапы с целочисленными ключами  компаратор `Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o)` излишний, так как он фактически совпадает с компаратором по умолчанию.